# backbone model - howto execute outer functions from event handlers?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, this, underscore.js

In Backbonejs, is it possible to initialize event handlers in a loop even when the handlers make use of the functions in the outer model?

For e.g. how can I get something like the below to work?

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    eventHandlers: {
        onerror: function(e) {
            this.myErrorHandler(e); // doesnt work
        },
    },

    initialize: function () {
        var myObj = {}
        _.each(eventHandlers, function(value, key) {
            myObj[key] = value;
        }, this);
    },

    myErrorHandler: function(e) {
        console.error('my error handler', e);
    }
});
```

How do I get the Model's error handler function (myErrorHandler) to be called from the event handlers that are declared in a sub object? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

TIA

Comment: Why not just `this.on('error', this.myErrorHandler, this)` instead of the `_.each()`?

Comment: Actually there are several more handlers that I would like to add in a loop, just showed one here as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to execute each handler on event defined by its key, bound to the model instance?

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    eventHandlers: {
        error: function(e) {
            this.myErrorHandler(e); // doesnt work
        }
    },

    initialize: function () {
        var _this = this;
        _.each(this.eventHandlers, function(value, key) {
            _this.on(key, _(value).bind(_this));
        });
    },

    myErrorHandler: function(e) {
        console.error('my error handler', e);
    }
});
```

But what if you want to have several handlers for the same event?

Comment: Thanks! Binding to the this variable inside the for loop was the missing link.